# How can this argument be of use if doesn't have a value anymore?

Tags: python, function, time

I'm currently doing a course in Coursera called "Learn to program: the fundamentals" and it's based on Python, which is the language I want to learn. I thought I was getting most of the stuff they were teaching, but once I came across the first assignment I got blocked because I didn't know how to do the code the *function* needed.

At the end, I figured that I could just find the code somewhere else and then try to make sense of it, so I have a better understanding of the concept in the future, but it wasn't the case.

Here's the code I didn't get that much:

**I will refer to the code above with a text below it**

```
def to_24_hour_clock(hours):
    """ (number) -> number

    hours is a number of hours since midnight. Return the
    hour as seen on a 24-hour clock.

    Precondition: hours >= 0

    >>> to_24_hour_clock(24)
    0
    >>> to_24_hour_clock(48)
    0
    >>> to_24_hour_clock(25)
    1
    >>> to_24_hour_clock(4)
    4
    >>> to_24_hour_clock(28.5)
    4.5
    """

    return hours % 24


### Write your get_hours function definition here:
def get_hours(sec_since_midnight):
    '''(int) -> int

    Return the number of get_hours that have 
    elapsed since midnight, as seen on a 24-hour clock.

    >>> get_hours(3800)
    1
    >>> get_hours (3600)
    1
    >>> get_hours (9000)
    2
    '''
    return sec_since_midnight // 3600
```

This one I *kinda* get it.

```
### Write your get_minutes function definition here:
def get_minutes(sec_since_midnight):
    '''(int) -> int
   
    Return the number of get_minutes that have elapsed
    since midnight as seen on a clock.

    >>> get_minutes(3800)
    3
    >>> get_minutes(3600)
    0
    >>> get_minutes(900)
    15
    '''

    return (sec_since_midnight - get_hours(sec_since_midnight) * 3600) // 60
```

Here is where I get lost, like… I get that **(sec_since_midnight** is going to subtract from **get_hours**, but how? This last one doesn't have a value anymore... right? Otherwise, what would it be?

I tried running it without the argument's names and just applying the value to both arguments (i.g. (3600 - 3600 * 3600) // 60) but I didn't get the result I was supposed to.

I know this comes from reusing functions and stuff, but I guess I didn't get it that clearly.

```
### Write your get_seconds function definition here:
def get_seconds(sec_since_midnight):
    '''(int) -> int

    The parameter is a number of seconds since midnight. Return
    the number of get_seconds that have elapsed since midnight as
    seen on    a clock.

    >>> get_seconds(3800)
    20
    >>> get_seconds(3600)
    0
    >>> get_seconds(912)
    12
    '''
    return sec_since_midnight - get_hours(sec_since_midnight)*3600 - get_minutes (sec_since_midnight)*60
```

That would be it. English is not my first language, so I apologize if it was hard to read somewhere, I tried to explain my doubt the best I could.

Thank you in advance, guys :)

PD: If any of you knows of any course(s), platforms I could use to keep learning, practicing and improving, please let me know. I'm going for the path of Data Science :).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't have a value"?

Comment: Note that `get_hours(3600)` will be evaluated to 1, so you would get `(3600 - 1 * 3600) // 60`. That is what functions are for.

Comment: Also, under the first block you say "this one I *kinda* get it", which implies that there's something that you don't understand. Don't be afraid and ask about what you don't understand there too.

Comment: @Shinratensei for example, if I use the code 

`def whatever(whatever1): 
    return whatever // 2`

I know `whatever1 = random number` is the one going to be //'ed in this case. 
But, if I use something like 

`def whatever2(whatever3): 
    return (whatever3 - whatever(whatever1) * 3600) // 60`

I know `whatever3 = whatever value I decide to use`, but what value is taking 'whatever1' since it wasn't specified in its own function and it's just an argument?

Sorry if you still don't get it :/

Comment: `whatever1` would indeed be undefined, but that's not the case in the block you've posted since the variable being used is `sec_since_midnight`, which is defined in the parameters of the function. No names in the function are undefined.

Comment: Okay, can you guide me to where it is defined? Sorry if I'm making dumb questions